# qemu error: mmap stack: Out of memory

Tags: qemu, chroot

I'm trying to use alpine linux aarch64 on my x86-64 linuxhost like this:

```
chroot ./rootfs qemu-aarch64-static /bin/sh
```

I then reach the prompt and start using it.
Sometimes (randomly), I get an error message:

> mmap stack: Out of memory

How can I fix this error? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After mounting /proc /sys and /dev inside the chroot dir
things appear to be working normally now.